# How do I set environment variables to Next.js (SSR) after it is built?

Tags: docker, next.js, environment-variables

I have this Next.js app (using SSR, using `next start`) which communicates with a server externally, and the server URL would have to be dynamic. This information, among other things, are dynamic variables that I would probably only have after initial deployment.

I have currently dockerized this Next.js app, so it gets built, then pushed to Docker Hub.

The "happy-flow" for the end user who would be using my app is that they should be able to pull the docker image of the prebuilt frontend, pass an `env_file` through docker-compose and just be able to use it as they wish.

All the examples ([this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) and [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration)) I've seen have explained how to pass ENV to Next.js but the ENV has to be passed during build time, which defeats the purpose of portability.

Comment: could [this](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2021/04/buildtime-vs-runtime-environment-variables-nextjs-docker/) help?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli Unfortunately no, none of the methods worked for my specific use case of being able to pass env vars AFTER building the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by making use of this package ([react-env](https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env)), which isn't the most ideal solution but works for now.

It has a couple of setup steps and opinionated configuration to it, but works as expected for anyone who's looking for a solution to pass env vars after the Next.js app has been built.